# Web Api 2 - converting values and combine values from sub query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In a Web API 2 project, using EF, i am trying to get a controller to return a list of items from the database. That simple enough.
The problem comes, when i want it to return a single coordinate value, calculated from a function, below, based on a list of locations.
All the method does, is calculating a center point, based on a list of GeoLocation values. That method works as expected. What does not work, is the controller action.

1. Running the below code, results in a

   'LINQ to Entities does not
       recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and
       this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
2. I am currently using `item.Locations.FirstOrDefault().cX`, which i
   know will not work, as it will always return the same value. But
   `item.cX` does not work. So what should i use, to make my statement
   work as intended?

The code

IdentityModel:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<myModel.Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string cX { get; set; }
    public string cY { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<GeoCoordinate> GetList()
    {
        var items = db.Items
            .Select(item => new ItemDTO()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
        Title = item.Title
                Coordinates = item.Locations
                    .Select(LocationsItem => new GeoCoordinate() //System.Device.Location
                    {
                        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Locations.FirstOrDefault().cX),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Locations.FirstOrDefault().cY)
                    })
                    .ToList()
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinates));

        return items.AsQueryable();
    }
```

GetCentralGeoCoordinate function:

```
public static GeoCoordinate GetCentralGeoCoordinate(IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> geoCoordinates)
    {
        if (geoCoordinates.Count() == 1)
        {
            return geoCoordinates.Single();
        }

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
        {
            var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
            var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

            x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
            y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
            z += Math.Sin(latitude);
        }

        var total = geoCoordinates.Count();

        x = x / total;
        y = y / total;
        z = z / total;

        var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

        return new GeoCoordinate(centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI, centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried double.Parse(item.Locations.FirstOrDefault().cX) instead of Convert.Double(item.Locations.FirstOrDefault().cX)?

Comment: ToDouble can't be translated into SQL - EF will try to convert the whole IQueryable part into one SQL query; there it fails, because converting is not possible like that in SQL. you'll have to use db.Items.ToList()... for this task.

Comment: @ChrisBartlett Yes, same result.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I know it wont work as it is now - but i am unsure how i can modify my code, to make it work - hence my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public IQueryable<GeoCoordinate> GetList()
{
    // this ToList fetches the data from the db. 
    // now you don't have to worry about convert inside EF
    var sourceItems = db.Items.Include(x => x.Locations).ToList(); 

    // Select updated to answer part 2 (I believe).
    var items = sourceItems.Select(item => new ItemDTO()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Title = item.Title
            Coordinates = item.Locations
                .Select(itemLocation => new GeoCoordinate()
                {
                    Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(itemLocation.cX),
                    Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(itemLocation.cY)
                })
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinates));

    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```